# I got a the entity type requires primary key error

Tags: c#, entity-framework

When i try to connect with my database and my class i got this error
[image] But this error appear just for my Consoles,KeyboardMouse and Headphones tables. But they have already primary keys.
[image]

and here is my context class

```
public class EcommContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=.;Database=eCommerce;Trusted_Connection=true");

    }
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Card> Cards { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Consoles> Consoles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Headphone> Headphones { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Mouse> Mouses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MousePad> MousePads { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Keyboard> Keyboards { get; set; }
    public DbSet<KeyboardAndMouse> KeyboardMouse { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Gamepad> Gamepads { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Computer> Computers { get; set; }
}
```

And my entity classes

```
public class Headphone:IEntity
{
    public int HeadphonesId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public bool IsWireless { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public bool IsGaming { get; set; }
}

public class KeyboardAndMouse:IEntity
{
    public int KmId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
}

public class Consoles:IEntity
{
    public int ConsoleId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public int GamepadNumber { get; set; }
    public int Capacity { get; set; }
}
```

How can I solve that. Does anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your entity class you need to use `[Key]` annotation for primary key field. Try like below.

```
public class Headphone:IEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int HeadphonesId { get; set; }
}

public class KeyboardAndMouse:IEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int KmId { get; set; }
}

public class Consoles:IEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int ConsoleId { get; set; }
}
```

Please check this out for more information : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations#configuring-a-primary-key

**FYI** - By convention, a property named `Id` or `<type name>Id` will be configured as the primary key of an entity.

So if you had `HeadphoneId` field in `Headphone` class then it will select that column as primary key by convention and no need to use `[Key]` annotation or `Fluent API` to define Primary key field.